# Not sure what’s going on... betta help please

Tags: betta

[image]

Not sure what is up with this guy. He’s been very lethargic and we can’t seem to figure out what’s up. We’ve check ph nitrates etc with test strips. He’s in a 3.5g filtered tank with bubble rock, heater, 2 plastic plants and a plastic hose. Every now and then he swims around and seems to eat. But 95% of the time he is laying on the bottom... thoughts?

Comment: Plastic hide* in the tank

Comment: You need to test for Ammonia. PH, Nitrates, Nitrite etc can all be tolerated in varying amounts (nitrites less so) but any Ammonia in your tank will start to kill your fish. The strips cannot test for ammonia, you'll need a [proper test kit](https://www.amazon.co.uk/API-Aquarium-Freshwater-Master-800-Piece/dp/B000255NCI/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1541419131&sr=8-2&keywords=test+kit+master).